# Fold with Data.Map.adjust

Tags: dictionary, haskell, iteration, fold

I'm trying to get the correct function which will update one or multiple value by iterating over a list of key.

Example:

```
s1 = Data.Map.fromList [(1,"value1"), (2,"value2"), (3,"value3")]
```

By passing to the function the list `[1,2]` and the update value `"plus"`, the list should look like this:

```
[(1,"plus"), (2,"plus"), (3,"value3")]
```

Here is what I tried so far, I'm having a hard time implementing the function which iterate over the list of key to update

```
changeValue map newValue xs = foldr (\k map -> Map.adjust (newValue)(xs)(sm)) map m
```

What should I look for from there? I don't think I could use `map` in this situation.

Comment: It looks as though you're using one of the *Map* modules in *containers*. Would [mapWithKey](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:mapWithKey) work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, you're on the right track.

A fold is indeed what you need. You need to fold over the list of keys. The starting value is your original map, and it's being transformed during the fold.

You also correctly identified the function adjust.

`adjust` needs a function as the first argument. This function is `\_ -> newValue`, or just `const newValue`. I'd stay away using the name `map`, as it might cause confusion.

After these corrections, your program would probably look something like this:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

s1 = M.fromList [(1,"value1"), (2,"value2"), (3,"value3")]

changeValue m newValue ks = foldr (\k m -> M.adjust (const newValue) k m) m ks

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ changeValue s1 "plus" [1, 2]
```

Comment: This is a case where `foldl'` is a better choice than `foldr`.